# Multi column print format misaligned

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am writing a simple python program connecting to my Mongo database to extract all Clients using Custom Applications (other than Oracle E-biz, SAP,etc.) as shown below:

def Customers_Applications():

```
  try:
                    cursor = customers.find({},{"_id":1,"Applications":1}).sort("Applications",pymongo.DESCENDING)
                    counter = 0
                    Total  = customers.count()
                    for doc in cursor:
                            for app in doc['Applications']:
                                    if app not in ["Oracle E-Biz", "SAP", "PeopleSoft"]:
                                            print "Customer Name: %s \t Application Name: %s" % (doc['_id'],'' .join(app))
                                            #print "Customer Name: %s \t Application Name: %s" % (doc['_id'],' ' .join(doc['Applications']))
                                            counter += 1
                    print "\n"
                    print "Total %s Customers : %s (%s%%)" %(x,counter, counter*100/Total)
 except Exception as e:
                    print "Unexpected error:", type(e), e
```

While printing the output it misaligns the 2nd field output depending of values of 1st field as shown:

> ```
> Customer Name: Zinga   Application Name: Trizetto
> Customer Name: Bongo   Application Name: Trizetto
> Customer Name: Bank of Jamunda     Application Name: Actimiz
> Customer Name: Bank of Tongo   Application Name: TouchPoint
> Customer Name: Copa    Application Name: Sharepoint
> Customer Name: US-Copa     Application Name: SharePoint
> Customer Name: Camba   Application Name: Kronos
> ```

I am using "\t" option between 2 fields but it's not helping in alignment while printing.  I am newbie to this world and am pretty sure making some rookie mistakes.

Appreciate your guidance from Python gurus. thanks for your time and attention.

-Viral

Answer (score 0):

`\t` - is usually counted as 4 spaces, you could use .format to have this algined

```
 print "{0} {1} {2} {3}"
   .format("Customer Name: ", doc['_id'], 'Application Name: ', 'data'))
```

Comment: Thanks Professor for guidance and tried using it but no luck :-)                         for app in doc['Applications']:
                                        if app not in ["Oracle E-Biz", "SAP", "PeopleSoft"]:
                                                print "{0} {1} {2} {3}" .format("Customer Name: ", doc['_id'], 'Application Name: ', app)
                                                #print "Customer Name: %s \t Application Name: %s" % (doc['_id'],'' .join(app))
                                                counter += 1

Comment: Output:Customer Name:  Zinga Application Name:  Trizetto
Customer Name:  Bongo Application Name:  Trizetto
Customer Name:  Bank of Jamunda Application Name:  Actimiz
Customer Name:  Bank of Tongo Application Name:  TouchPoint
Customer Name:  Copa Application Name:  Sharepoint
Customer Name:  US-Copa Application Name:  SharePoint
Customer Name:  Camba Application Name:  Kronos

Answer (score 0):

I tried the recommended options but no luck:)

===================================
def Customers_Applications():

```
  try:
                    cursor = customers.find({},{"_id":1,"Applications":1}).sort("Applications",pymongo.DESCENDING)
                    counter = 0
                    Total  = customers.count()
                    for doc in cursor:
                            for app in doc['Applications']:
                                    if app not in ["Oracle E-Biz", "SAP", "PeopleSoft"]:
                                            print "Customer Name: %s \t Application Name: %s" % (doc['_id'],'' .join(app))
                                            #print "Customer Name: %s \t Application Name: %s" % (doc['_id'],' ' .join(doc['Applications']))
                                            counter += 1
                    print "\n"
                    print "Total %s Customers : %s (%s%%)" %(x,counter, counter*100/Total)
 except Exception as e:
```

## print "Unexpected error:", type(e), e

## Output is still showing as:

Customer Name:  Zinga Application Name:  Trizetto
Customer Name:  Bongo Application Name:  Trizetto
Customer Name:  Bank of Jamunda Application Name:  Actimiz
Customer Name:  Bank of Tongo Application Name:  TouchPoint
Customer Name:  Copa Application Name:  Sharepoint
Customer Name:  US-Copa Application Name:  SharePoint
Customer Name:  Camba Application Name:  Kronos